# Copy a file in bash that is actively written to in bash

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to be able to copy a text file to another location and then delete the contents of this text file (without deleting the file).

At the moment I am doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0

    for filename in `find . -name "*_list" -print`
    do
      while read -r line
      do
        echo $line 
        sync
        echo "### Trace Info ###" > log.txt
        sync
        python worker.py "$line"
        echo $line > traces/trace$count.txt
        sync
        sync
        sleep 1
        sync
        sync
        cp log.txt traces/trace$count.txt
        #cp log.txt traces/log.txt
        sync
        sleep 1
        count=$((count+1))
      done < $filename
    done
```

But calling sync and sleep it not working for me, instead I get file like this:
(NOTE: the python file is not writing to log.txt CacheGrind is.)

```
CachegrindMemMod/vg-in-place --tool=cachegrind --trace-children=yes /usr/sbin/mysqld 2>log.txt

cat trace10.txt | xxd
0000000: 2323 2320 5472 6163 6520 496e 666f 2023  ### Trace Info #
0000010: 2323 0a00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ##..............
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

This trace has 4 megs of zeros which should have been text.

```
ls -la trace10.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4350121 2012-04-29 15:34 trace10.txt
```

I am guessing there is some caching going on that is preventing me from being able to get the accrual text.  Any ideas would be great.

If you are interested the file should contain a list of memory addresses retrieved from a modified version of CacheGrind that looks like this:

```
Dw: 0x4916e30
Dw: 0x4916df0
Dw: 0x4916db0
Dw: 0x4916d70
Dr: 0x4916d30
Dr: 0x4916cf0
Dr: 0x4916cb0
Dr: 0x4916c70
Dr: 0x4916c30
Dr: 0x4916bf0
Dr: 0x4916bb0
Dr: 0x4916b70
Dr: 0x4916b30
Dr: 0x4916af0
Dr: 0x4916ab0
```

Also modified version of CacheGrind can be found [here](https://github.com/kportertx/CachegrindMemMod/tree/master/cachegrind)

Additional Info:
I noticed some file only contain the header and no null data.  This also leads me to think its an I/O caching problem

Comment: There's no need to start a subshell with `$(...)` to increment `$count`. You can do the same with `count=$[count+1]`

Comment: @dschulz: it's `$((expr))` a different thing, and it's not executed in a subshell.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I was wrong, thank you! TIL about `$((expression))`. For a long time I thought anything starting with `$(` had something to do with a subshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who's writing in that log.txt file? The python script? Is it working in the background? If so, why are trying to copy the (not completed) file? Why are you trying to sync in the bash script?

- Extend the script so it allows the log file as a command line parameter, so each invocation is going to write to a separate file.

Comment: The python file is only executing commands against the program I am tracing.  CacheGrind is writing to log.txt and it takes a bit for the initialization of this program and I only need the traces of specific commands and not the initialization.  So I have to copy an incomplete file and delete the contents after I copy.  I'll add the CacheGrind command above.

Comment: that's very error prone, you will have timing issues. just process the output files with grep, awk, etc...

Comment: Aha! Your problem is that nothing tells CacheGrind to seek back to the beginning of the file. It goes on from where it was, and the kernel fills the space in between with zeroes (which may not actually take up space on disk).  I agree with Karoly, what you are trying to do is very error prone, you should just postprocess the file after cachegrind is done with it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I do not know how this could be done.  I suppose I could keep track of the line counts each time I would have copied to another file then process the file later with the line numbers to separate into different files.

Comment: @Zack hmm interesting.  I noticed there is some trace data at the bottom.  I suppose this could be all the data (I was expecting more).  So could it be that all the zeros is that CacheGrind continued to print at the same line and all the prior lines are zeroed out?

Comment: We are currently implementing the version where we keep track of line numbers.

Comment: I don't understand why you think checking the file after a 1 second sleep is a good idea. It doesn't make sense. You have to post-process the whole output file. Post a new question with the format + what you want to keep / filter out.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath well, we are not really filtering anything out.  We are storing the memory traces of different commands to different files.  There really wouldn't be anything to grep, the best I can do is get the length of the file before and after I issue a command to the program being traced.  This is a security related project.  The goal is to see if we can extract any meaningful information about a set of programs given only their memory traces.  If you look at the modified CacheGrind output above, that is what it looks like throughout the file.

Comment: Ok keeping track of the lengths seems to work pretty good.  I'm going to call this solved.  Thanks for all of yalls help!

Comment: @kporter "...continued to print at the same line..." Yes, if by 'line' you mean 'byte offset from the beginning of the file'.  UNIX files don't have any internal structure, and that is a Good Thing.

Comment: @Zack, we just run wc -l at the beginning and end of a command execution.  The output we are interested it in printed line by line to the file.

Comment: @Zack sorry thought you were critiquing the solution didn't realize you were referring to a point that has no bearing on the solution.  Thanks for the input.